# python flask - global list - remove elements if list exist

Tags: python, flask

my actual code is :

```
files1   = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('files1/*.txt')]
files2   = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('files2/*.txt')]
files3   = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('files3/*.txt')]

@app.route('/remove/<dictionary>/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
@nocache
def remove_dictionary(dictionary, filename):
    try:
        global eval(dictionary)
        eval(dictionary).remove(filename)
        return '{} file successful removed'.format(filename)
    except Exception as error:
        return str(error), 404
```

when i get path "/remove/files1/file333.txt" i want to remove filename from list files1.

error:

```
F:\dev\python_api>server2_beta.py
  File "F:\dev\python_api\server2_beta.py", line 335
    global eval(dictionary)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Nooo.... don't use `eval`. Especially not when people can inject content through a URL: now people can inject arbitrary code...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you, im forgot about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **never use `eval(..)` unless you absolutely have to**, and especially do not use it in combination with Flask: what if a user visits the url: `remove/import os; os.rmdir('/')/bar`? Now it can result in the fact that content on your server will be removed.

Furthermore you better **limit the amount of `global`s**: it is an anti-pattern: it usually is a sign that something is wrong with the design of your application. Only in very limited occasions these are really helpful.

You better **use a dictionary here**:

```
files = {
    'files1': [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('files1/*.txt')]
    'files2': [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('files2/*.txt')]
    'files3': [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('files3/*.txt')]
}

@app.route('/remove//', methods=['GET'])
@nocache
def remove_dictionary(dictionary, filename):
    try:
        files[dictionary].remove(filename)
        return '{} file successful removed'.format(filename)
    except Exception as error:
        return str(error)
```

Now this function will error if someone passes a `dictionary` to your function that is not `'files1'`, `'files2'` or `'files3'`. So you made it very restrictive to what people can enter. They do not have any means to execute arbitrary code.